# XSLT nested nodes transformation

Tags: xslt

I have xml and xsl for its  transformation
The problem is I dont know nesting level of the  node I  want  to  transform.   transformation  works fine  when  there is  no nesting and my  element is a root  node. Otherwise it  doesnt. I'm  sure  I'm missing something. How can I  get node if I dont know  about the nesting structure  of xml to parse. I mean my element can be  inside

```
<stack>
    <cell>
        <myelem>text here</myelem>
    </cell>
<stack>
```

or

```
<forms>
    <form>
        <stack>
            <cell>
                <stack>
                    <cell>
                        <myelem>text here</myelem>
                    </cell>
                <stack>
            </cell>
        <stack>
    </form>
</forms>
```

or some more complicated structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
//myelem
```

to select `myelem` anywhere in the document, starting from the root.

The downside of this is:

1. slower performance;
2. it does select **all** `myelem` nodes at any level - i.e. you don't get to choose between similar-named elements at different levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="myelem">
    ....
</xsl:template>
```

will apply to `myelem` no matter what its nesting level, given all the normal caveats about how templates are matched and applied.

Comment: It might or it might not - depending on what else is in the stylesheet.